Could not attach to pid when trying to run iPad app on Mac M2
Developping an app that runs well on iPhone and iPad but when I try to run in on M2 Mac, I get the following error: "Could not attach to pid : “####” attach failed (Not allowed to attach to process.  Look in the console messages (Console.app), near the debugserver entries, when the attach failed.  The subsystem that denied the attach permission will likely have logged an informative message about why it was denied.)"
Impossible to run the app.
I searched in the Console.app but there was nothing there that lead me to understand the issue.
Rebooted Mac, relaunched Xcode, executed "DevToolsSecurity -enable".
Also tried everything that is mentioned in the below post. The only thing that allow me to launch the app is to disable "Debug Executable" in the scheme, which is not really practicable because execution does not stop on break points. I have also tried to randomly change many settings in the scheme without any success.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/120282?page=2
Any solution to this?

I found the solution to my own question: This issue occurred because I had previously installed the app for testing after archiving it (Archive... Release for testing, install .ipa file on same Mac) and tried later to run it from Xcode (ctrl+R). There is some kind of conflict between the installed app and the app ran from Xcode.
The steps to solve the problem are as follow:

Force to quit the app that is bouncing in the dock.
Delete the app in the Application folder.
Delete /Users/#username#/Library/Containers/com.apple.CoreDevice.CoreDeviceService/Data/Library/Caches/AppInstallationBinaryDeltas/#bundle identifier#
Delete /Users/#username#/Library/Containers/#app GUID#. To find the app GUID, search for a folder with the app name in /Users/#username#/Library/Containers/#app GUID#/Data/Library/Application Support.

After performing these steps, the app runs normally from Xcode on Mac with ctrl+R.
There may be a better way to uninstall the app but I could not find any.
